# Given an integer $n$, how to locate divisors $p$, $q$ such that $(pq) \bmod (p+q) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**Problem:**

Given $n$, find $p$, $q$ such that

- $n = pq$ and
- $ (pq)\bmod (p+q) = 1$

**My Effort:**

To get the minimum modulus, My initial hunch was $p$, $q$ should be as close to each other as possible. ie the two divisors on either side of square root.
But playing with some numbers don't quite suggest so.

```
n = 100000
p   q   (p*q) mod (p+q) 
1 100000 100000
2 50000 49998
4 25000 24988
5 20000 19980
8 12500 12444
10 10000 9910
16 6250 6010
20 5000 4620
25 4000 3400
32 3125 2133
40 2500 940
50 2000 1600
80 1250 250
100 1000 1000
125 800 100
160 625 305
200 500 600
250 400 550
```

Since for most of the n there would be no solution, so it might be possible to know if 1 mod can exist or not without factoring

Comment: $p,q$ have to be relatively prime. That is necessary, but not sufficient.

Comment: You want to find $k$ such that $n \pmod{k + \frac{n}{k}} = 1$. This sounds like a competition/CTF problem, but anyways, I believe this is hard.

Comment: If $n\equiv 2\pmod3,$ there is no pair. That's because any $pq=n$ has $p+q$ divisible by $3,$ and if $n\bmod (p+q)=1,$ then $n\bmod 3=1.$ Similarly for $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$

Comment: Every answer I can find involves factorizing. For example, there is a parameterization of all $n$ by positive tuples $(u,v,w,x)$ such that $uv-wx=1.$ But even enumerating those tuples involves factoring.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am fine with an approach which can reduce the problem of factoring $n$ to something of order of factoring $n^{1/2}$.

Comment: The smallest $n$ with two pairs $(p,q)$ is $n=414726$ with $(p,q)=(338,1227)$ and $(p,q)=(818,507).$ There are $22224$ triples $(n,p,q)$ with $n\leq 1,000,000,000,$ with $22219$ distinct $n$ values.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a way of enumeration values $n$ that have a solution.

$pq\bmod (p+q)=1$ iff there is a $k$ such that $pq=k(p+q)+1.$

$pq=(p+q)k+1$ if and only if $(p-k)(q-k)=k^2+1.$ So given any $ab=k^2+1,$ we can get a pair $(p,q)=(a+k,b+k)$ and $n=pq.$

In particular, $a=k^2+1,b=1$ gives $(p,q)=(k^2+k+1,k+1)$ and $n=k^3+2k^2+2k+1.$ That gives an infinite set of values $n$ that have a solution.

Now, $k^2+1$ factorizations come from Gaussian integer factorizations of $1+ki=(c_1+d_1i)(c_2+d_2i)$ with $c_i>0,$ $d_i\geq 0$ and $c_1c_2-d_1d_2=1$ and $k=c_1d_2+c_2d_1, a=c_1^2+d_1^2$ and $b=c_2^2+d_2^2.$

Then $$\begin{align}n&=(a+k)(b+k)\\&=(c_1(d_2+c_1)+d_1(c_2+d_1))(c_2(d_1+c_2)+d_2(c_1+d_2))\\&=c_1d_2(c_2+d_1)^2+c_2d_1(c_1+d_2)^2+(c_1c_2+d_1d_2)(d_1+c_2)(d_2+c_1)\end{align}$$

So, for $(c_1,d_1,c_2,d_2)=(3,2,3,4)$ gives $a=13,b=25,k=18$ and $n=(13+18)(25+18)=1333.$ That's a large $n$ for a relatively small set of values.

Given $c_1,d_1$ relatively prime, we can solve $c_1x-d_1y=1$ for all positive integers, so enumerating the tuples isn't as hard as factorizing. So if we want to find all $n<N$ which have a solution this might be a good approach, since the formula for $n$ is increasing as each of $c_i,d_i$ increases.